# "to learn and to persevere" vs. "to learn and persevere"

Tags: prepositions, conjunction-reduction

Which one of the following two sentences is grammatically correct?

1. I can attest to how my willingness to learn and to persevere through hard work will help me quickly grow to become an exceptional [job title].
2. I can attest to how my willingness to learn and persevere through hard work will help me quickly grow to become an exceptional [job title].

As you can see, I'm confused to whether the second verb (persevere) requires a preceding 'to'.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion they are both fine, but when you say "to learn and persevere" you are connecting those two actions together. They are not mutually exclusive like they are when you say "to learn and to persevere". I like the second example better because your intent is to learn and then persevere through hard work (they are connected together), and I feel that the word "to" is used one too many times in the first example.